# How to copy files via terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have read about copying files with terminal but these examples will help me a lot. So here is what I want to do:

Examples:

1. I have a file in `/home/levan/kdenlive untitelds.mpg` and I want to copy this file to `/media/sda3/SkyDrive` and do not want to delete any thing in SkyDrive directory.
2. I have a file in `/media/sda3/SkyDrive untitelds.mpg` and I want to copy this file to `/home/levan/kdenlive`  and do not want to delete any thing in kdenlive directory
3. I want to copy a folder from home directory to `sda3` and do not want to delete any thing on `sda3` directory and opposite
4. I want to cut a folder/file and copy to other place without deleting files in that directory I cut it into.

Comment: Simply with `cp -a file.txt newname.txt`.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

**1)** By using `-i` for interactive you will be asked if you would like to replace the file:

```
cp -i /home/levan/kdenlive/untitelds.mpg /media/sda3/SkyDrive/
```

or you can use `-b` to create a backup of your file:

```
cp -b /home/levan/kdenlive/untitelds.mpg /media/sda3/SkyDrive
```

---

**2)** Same as the above:

```
cp (-i or -b) /media/sda3/SkyDrive/untitelds.mpg /home/levan/kdenlive
```

---

**3)** Use `-R` for recursive and `-i` for interactive:

```
cp -Ri ~/MyFolder /sda3/
```

---

**4)** This last one can be done via the `mv` command, move is like cutting:

```
mv -i ~/MyFile ~/OtherFolder/MyFile
```

if you want to move a directory, use:

```
mv -Ri ~/MyDirectory ~/OtherDirectory/
```

Comment: Neat syntax highlighting! Not sure how you triggered that.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 you can use four spaces identation for code blocks, or you can surround small pieces of code with `s.

Comment: @EvandroSilva I know. I was referring to the fact that some of your code is shown in blue.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 I've noticed that too but I really have no clue of how does that work... :)

Comment: @WarriorIng64 That is triggered by the `bash` tag in the question.  highlighting will be enabled by default by the system. If you answer a question with `bash` tag, the hightlighting will follow bash style and so on.

Comment: @Anwar I was just partway through making a [Meta post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/4180/18612) on this when I saw your comment. Of course, I credited you in the answer. :)

Comment: I noticed that some of the directory paths in your answer (and others' too) have a trailing `/` at the end, while others don't. Does it make any difference?

Comment: @Ploni Actually, yes. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50533/24442) for more info

Answer (score 17):

When `~/Dropbox/RECENT/` is your current directory:

```
cp input.txt SORT/
```

> And I want to copy `input.txt` with another name in my current directory.

Again with `~/Dropbox/RECENT/` as current directory:

```
cp  input.txt newname.txt
```

Existing filenames can be auto-completed using <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Long version of the same copy command (when you are not in `~/Dropbox/RECENT/`):

```
cp /home/$USER/Dropbox/RECENT/input.txt /home/$USER/Dropbox/RECENT/SORT/
```

I put a `/` behind every directory. If `SORT` does NOT exist a `cp` will also create a file named `SORT` making you think something went wrong. Adding the `/` will have `cp` error out and not copy the file.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `cp` command.

Copying a file `something.txt` to file `folder`: use `cp something.txt folder/`

Copying a file `something.txt` to the current directory as `something2.txt`: use `cp something.txt something2.txt`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-T100TA:~/TestFolder$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 12 21:53 Folder1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   14 Mar 12 21:52 something.txt
ubuntu@ubuntu-T100TA:~/TestFolder$ ls -l Folder1/
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 14 Mar 12 21:53 something.txt
ubuntu@ubuntu-T100TA:~/TestFolder$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 12 21:54 folder
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   14 Mar 12 21:52 something.txt
ubuntu@ubuntu-T100TA:~/TestFolder$ ls -l folder/
total 0
ubuntu@ubuntu-T100TA:~/TestFolder$ cp something.txt folder/
ubuntu@ubuntu-T100TA:~/TestFolder$ ls -l folder/
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 14 Mar 12 21:55 something.txt
ubuntu@ubuntu-T100TA:~/TestFolder$ cp something.txt something2.txt 
ubuntu@ubuntu-T100TA:~/TestFolder$ ls -l
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 12 21:55 folder
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   14 Mar 12 21:55 something2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   14 Mar 12 21:52 something.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

you will better add the option **-a** to **cp** command to preserve file-datetime, file-stats, etc.:

```
cp -a input.txt ./SORT
cp -a input.txt newname.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -aAXhv /home/levan/kdenlive/untitelds.mpg  /media/sda3/SkyDrive/
```

This will copy the `untitelds.mpg` file in the SkyDrive directory without deleting anything

Comment: I'm not sure why my comment shows up in bold... wasn't intended to.

Comment: Read the formatting help by clicking the `?` just above the answer field, on the top right.

Answer (score 0):

use `cp` command. Type `man cp` from the terminal for more info.