# Copying files from DVD to hard disc?

Tags: command-line, dvd

I am trying to copy the contents of a DVD to a  folder (named `ANIL`) in Hard Disk
by using terminal.

Would somebody be able to provide me an example of the command line syntax required to achieve this?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The syntax** of `cp` (copy command in Terminal) from [**`man cp`**](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/cp.1.php) is as following:

```
NAME
       cp - copy files and directories

SYNOPSIS
       cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
       cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
       cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

DESCRIPTION
       Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
```

Insert your DVD and open your file manager and open the DVD by clicking on its name under devices:

[image]

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to getting its mountpoint(source path) and copy it.

[image]

Now open Terminal(use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type following:

```
cp -R /media/USERNAME/DVDNAME/* ~/ANIL/
```

Just replace `USERNAME` with your real username and `DVDNAME`(in my case it's `211+6211`) with yours. And also in above command your `ANIL` directory located in your Home directoy.

See also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195983/how-to-copy-files-via-terminal)

Comment: And you will need the DVD mounted and know it's mountpoint for the source, probably recursive option too, and then a destination within `/home/<user>`

Answer (score 2):

Install K3b (it is in the repository) and rip the DVD.