# How to copy files in Terminal as root user

Tags: command-line

I have 7000 files I would like to copy to a folder from `home/Videos` to `/usr/share/someplace`. How do I do this?

Comment: `sudo cp -R ~/Videos/* /usr/share/someplace/`

Comment: -1. This is a duplicate of so many questions.

Comment: @Parto copy uses the `cp` command and move uses `mv` furthermore, `mv` does not require `-R` whereas `cp` does.

Comment: @mchid Okay. How about --> http://askubuntu.com/questions/195983/how-to-copy-files-via-terminal?rq=1

Comment: @Parto still, that only shows how to copy a single file and not how to use a wildcard like `*` to copy all files in a given directory like the op wants to do here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all the files in the Videos folder to /usr/share/someplace, run this command:

```
sudo cp -R ~/Videos/* /usr/share/someplace
```

Keep in mind that /usr/share/someplace must exist so if you need to create that file before you start, run this command first:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/someplace
```

If you want to move all those files, you can use the `mv` command instead of `cp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `-v` option so u can see all the files that are copying.As

```
cp -rv ~/Videos/* /usr/share/someplace

OR
```

You can tar the files and copy them as:

```
tar -cvzf /usr/share/someplace/allfiles.tar.gz ~/Videos/* ....
```