# Pen Drive not reading after formatting-Permission denied

Tags: partitioning, permissions, usb-drive

Recently,I bought a pen drive:hp flash drive v301w.It was working fine when I first used it but when I formatted it,it does not appear on Files anymore, but it appears in Disks:
[image]

Then I created a partition in the name **hp v301w**.After that it does appear in Files but then this message pops up:

[image]

When I tried to copy a file into the pen drive,this screen appears:

[image]

The properties of the pen drive are:

[image]

The permissions state that:
      "*The Permissions of "hp v301w" could not be determined.*"

Is there any way to solve this?By the way I'm using Ubuntu 19.10.
Thank you in advance.

**Edit**:
When I input this command,it gave me the following output:

````
devananda@deva:~$ /media/devananda
bash: /media/devananda: Permission denied
devananda@deva:~$```
````

Also when I tried to open the file /media/ in terminal,I cannot find the command 'open in terminal'.

**Edit 2**:

Output of ls -al:

`````
total 3604
drwxr-xr-x 25 devananda devananda    4096 Dec  3 22:13 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root      root         4096 May 11  2019 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 devananda devananda    1702 Nov 28 18:36 0004000000159500.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 devananda devananda   35547 Nov  9 18:09 00040000001B5100.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 devananda devananda   19528 Jul 22 21:25 94A82AAA.pnach
-rw-------  1 devananda devananda   15770 Dec 25 20:34 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 devananda devananda     220 May 11  2019 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 devananda devananda    3771 May 11  2019 .bashrc
drwx------ 36 devananda devananda    4096 Dec 25 19:27 .cache
drwx------ 40 devananda devananda    4096 Dec 23 10:52 .config
-rw-rw-r--  1 devananda devananda     136 May 11  2019 Data.html
drwx------  3 root      root         4096 Nov 12 20:06 .dbus
drwxr-xr-x  5 devananda devananda    4096 Dec 13 14:09 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  7 devananda devananda    4096 Dec 22 12:50 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 18 devananda devananda    4096 Dec 27 11:18 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 devananda devananda    8980 May 11  2019 examples.desktop
drwx------  3 devananda devananda    4096 May 11  2019 .gnupg
-rw-------  1 devananda devananda   64914 Nov 22 08:14 .ICEauthority
drwxr-xr-x  5 devananda devananda    4096 May 11  2019 .ipython
drwxrwxr-x  3 devananda devananda    4096 May 12  2019 .java
drwx------  3 devananda devananda    4096 May 11  2019 .local
drwx------  6 devananda devananda    4096 Nov 17 09:08 .mozilla
-rw-rw-r--  1 devananda devananda 3388094 Jun 24  2019 mozilla.pdf
drwxr-xr-x  4 devananda devananda    4096 Dec 27 11:18 Music
drwxr-xr-x  9 devananda devananda    4096 Dec 25 20:41 Pictures
-rw-r--r--  1 devananda devananda     807 May 11  2019 .profile
drwxr-xr-x  2 devananda devananda    4096 May 11  2019 Public
-rw-------  1 devananda devananda       5 Nov 16 21:57 .python_history
drwxrwxr-x  4 devananda devananda    4096 May 17  2019 .renpy
-rw-r--r--  1 devananda devananda     153 Jun  9  2019 Ren.py
drwxr-xr-x 21 devananda devananda    4096 Dec 19 19:05 snap
-rw-rw-r--  1 devananda devananda      30 Sep 21 18:15 .so_sane_state
drwx------  2 devananda devananda    4096 May 11  2019 .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 devananda devananda       0 May 11  2019 .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxr-xr-x  2 devananda devananda    4096 May 11  2019 Templates
drwx------  5 devananda devananda    4096 Nov 24 17:53 .thunderbird
drwxr-xr-x  2 devananda games        4096 May 11  2019 .tuxtype
drwxrwxr-x  3 devananda devananda    4096 Aug 19 20:48 .var
drwxr-xr-x  4 devananda devananda    4096 Dec 23 21:16 Videos
-rw-rw-r--  1 devananda devananda     168 May 12  2019 .wget-hsts
drwxr-xr-x  4 devananda devananda    4096 Dec 27 17:40 .wine
-rw-r--r--  1 devananda devananda    3220 Dec 19  2018 winehq.key
devananda@deva:~$ ````
`````

Answer (score 2):

This problem can occur sometimes

Step 1: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to open  `terminal`. Step 2: Connect the USB and go to `/media/<user>` where `<user>` is your user name. Paste the command in the terminal

```
cd /media/devananda
```

Step 3: Type `ls -al` and see if the USB mount point is owned by `root`.

[image: screenshot]

Step 4: If it is owned by `root, then, type

```
sudo chown [username]:[username] [mount point]
```

and enter your password when asked

Comment: When I tried to enter this command in the terminal,this output came:

Comment: where is the output?

Comment: The output is in the edited post.Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Paste the output of Step 3 in the post, I will guide you further. You should have told that you are not well versed with command line.

Comment: I have pasted the output of the third step in the edited post.Thank you.

Comment: sudo chown [username] [mount point]     - worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The above answer should do the trick. But if you want a simpler approach and there is no data that you want to recover from that pendrive then,

`sudo apt install gparted`

Its a GUI based partition handler.

once it is installed, run it as root

`sudo gparted`

On the GUI select the pendrive from the drop down menu on the right hand side.

Right click on the drive and umount it first. If its already mounted, then right click and format it to whatever filesystem you want. Apply the changes and you should have the pendrive formatted and ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs very frequently when external pen drive have root permissions after format.

1. **You can copy files into external drive by using terminal with sudo permissions**

`$sudo cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY`

[How to copy files via terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/195990/388819)

2. **Delete your partition and create new partition (format external device) by using Disks**

[Disks Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fP7H.png)

3. **Grant permission into the External drive**

`chown -R user /mnt/point`

`chown -R user:group /mnt/point`

`chmod -R 775 /mnt/point`

[FilePermissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)