# How do I utilize a predesigned configuration file for Wireguard?

Tags: xubuntu, vpn, configuration

I am trying to get Wireguard to work on my xubuntu. Installation no problem, but when I tried to copy/move the configuration file my VPN provider sent me - I could not. That is, I don´t know how. It should sit in /etc/wireguard - but I do not know how to get it there via the terminal (or any other method I have tried).
Now I have tried:
sudo cp -b Home/Downloads/File_vpn.conf etc/wireguard
which gave
cp: cannot stat "Home/Downloads/File_vpn.conf" : No such file or directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy files via terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195983/how-to-copy-files-via-terminal)

Comment: Thanks for your help. At the umpteenth attempt I got it right. I missed one level in the chain of folders!! So on to next problem... At least something happened when I tried sudo wg-quick up... but " line 32: resolvconf: command not found...

Comment: Does that help you? https://superuser.com/questions/1500691/usr-bin-wg-quick-line-31-resolvconf-command-not-found-wireguard-debian?newreg=27709343ce1c48ed890fa67935017971